# stormcrawler: indexer.md.mapping - what happens if the metadata tag does not exist?

Tags: elasticsearch, stormcrawler

We have been having a weird issue with Stormcrawler 1.13.  On some (but not all) of our sites, we have a  `<meta name="college" content="thiscollege"/>` tag, and SC has the `indexer.md.mapping` set to `- parse.college=college`.  This seems to work correctly for the sites that have that meta tag set.

The problem we are running into is that if metatag is set to `thiscollege1` for pages 3.html, 4.html, and 5.html, then the crawler hits page25.html that does not have the meta tag, it *appears* to be re-using the value `thiscollege1` for the meta tag from 5.html and just stuffing it into the `college` field in the Elastic index.

Is there a way to set that so that it zeroes out or unsets that variable every time it heads to a new page so that the variable is not carried over?

Any advice on how to tweak this setting would be most appreciated!

It's been a bugger of a problem to chase down, as some records just seem to have random entries in them. It wasn't till I matched up the records with some of the status records, sorted by NextFetchDate, that I saw that it could be a carried over variable. I am going to try to set up a specific test with just a couple pages to specifically prove/disprove the theory, but right now it's the only thing that fits what is happening.

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should happen only if you have listed *parse.college* in the values for the config *metadata.transfer*.

Comment: OH - yes, I do have that set. All has become clear. Thank you!